# How to preventDefault() in modal login form

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, forms, materialize

I'm working with Spring Framework MVC and I'm trying to make my login form work but I'm really a beginner in ajax.

Here is my index.jsp code.

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal2">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('modal1').style.display = 'none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

<!-- Modal Content -->
<form:form id="login-form" method="POST" commandName="users" class="modal-content2 animate">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="<c:url value=" /public/images/rsz_default-user.png "/>"   alt="Avatar2" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        <label id="Correo"><b>Correo</b></label>
        <input name="correo" id="correo" class="form-control" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
      </p>
      <button type="submit"onclick="submitForm();"class="cyan">Enviar</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('modal1').style.display = 'none'" class="red">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Olvidaste tu <a href="#">Contraseña?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form:form>

</div>
```

Here is my LoginController:

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String login(@ModelAttribute("users") Users u,BindingResult result) {
  String returnText;
  this.userValidations.validate(u, result);
  Users user = checkUser(u.getCorreo(), u.getPassword());
  if ((u.getCorreo().equals(user.getCorreo())) && (u.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword()))) {
    returnText = "¡Bienvenid@ " + user.getNombre() + "!";
  } else {
    returnText = "Usuario incorrecto";
  }
  return returnText;
}
```

and this is my ajax function to submit the modal form if the login was successfull.

```js
function submitForm(){
    $('#login-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        alert("Estoy aca");
        $.ajax('/index.htm', {
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Estoy aca");
                Materialize.toast(result);
            }
        });

    });  
}
```

My problem here is when I complete the form correctly the submit is working as expected but if I put wrong data into the form I don't know how to catch the error into the modal without refresh or redirect the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, why are you binding to the submit event in the onclick event. That is not necessary, since you are already binding to the onclick event, and you are programatically executing the ajax call...

Now to your actual question, if you return **false** in any eventhadler function, the event is cancelled.

One easy way to do it would be  making a validator javascript function, and return false if the validator is not satisfied..

```
function isEverythingValid(){
  var isFormValid = true;

  //Validate all your form here

  //for example:
  if(document.getElementById('someId').value == ""){
    isFormValid = isFormValid && false;
  } 
  return isFormValid ;
}

function submitForm(){
 if(isEverythingValid()){
       $.ajax('/index.htm', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Estoy aca");
            Materialize.toast(result);
         }
       });
   }
  else{
     return false;
 }
```